# Getting an error Call to a member function getCount() on a non-object

Tags: yii2

i am using sqldataprovider and i am geting a Call to a member function getCount() on a non-object error. i dont know what have i done wrong. below is my controller code

```
 public function actionTicketbookingreport()
    {
    $count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM screen_ticket_booking_history WHERE      status=:status
            ', [':status' => 0])->queryScalar();
            $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
                'sql' => 'SELECT A1.booking_id As Booking_id,
                        A1.booking_date As Booking_date,
                        A2.movie_name As Movie,
                        A3.theatre_name As Theatre,
                        A1.amount As Amount

                        FROM 
                        screen_ticket_booking_history A1

                        LEFT OUTER JOIN movies A2 ON A1.movie_id=A2.id
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN theatres A3 ON A1.theatre_id=A3.id
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN users_backend A4 ON A3.users_backend_id=A4.id

                        WHERE A1.booking_date >= :start_date
                        AND   A1.booking_date <= :end_date
                        AND   A3.users_backend_id = :id',

                'params' => [':start_date' => $year_start,':end_date'=>$year_end,':id'=> $userid],
                'totalCount' => $count,
            ]);


            // get the user records in the current page
            $models = $dataProvider->getModels(); 
             //no dataprovider




                    return $this->render('index',
                        [   'model'             => $model,
                            'dataProvider'      => $models,

                        ]);
                }
```

Comment: when i used printr($models);die(); there is result

Comment: So if $models has result that means that the problem is somewhere else... dataProvider looks okey

Comment: its my first question n thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I see where what is wrong

```
              return $this->render('index',
                    [   'model'             => $model,
                        'dataProvider'      => $models,

                    ]);
```

getModels() returns just an array of elements. If You are trying to generate gridView or something like that You should give whole dataProvider. So it should be

```
'dataProvider'      => $dataProvider,
```

Comment: i tried it but i got another error: Message format 'number' is only supported for integer values. You have to install PHP intl extension to use this feature.

Comment: so install intl extension